# How to compute threshold?

Tags: keras, regression, predictive-modeling, anomaly-detection

I would like to detect anomalies for univariate time series data. Most [examples](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mineshjethva/timeseries-anomaly-detection-using-rnn-autoencoder/notebook) on internet show that, after you predict the model, you calculate a threshold for the training data and a MAE test loss and compare them to detect anomalies. So I am thinking is this the correct way of doing it? Shouldn't it be a different threshold value for each data? Also, why do all of the examples only compute MAE loss for anomalies?

Comment: Can you point to a sample reference for this?

Comment: Hi @RalphWinters, I have added a link in the question at 'examples'.

Comment: What kind of models are you thinking about using? What is the application?

Comment: @RalphWinters, you can find details in my other [questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/110961/what-model-and-attributes-would-be-good-for-this-data). I have tried keras dense layer, conv1d and lstm.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one way of doing it. The example used a training set with a small amount of noise to calculate the maximum of the mean average error between a data point and the prediction as the threshold for detecting a abnormality. The training set is being used to represent the 'normal' time series model.  The assumption is that any point beyond a maximum MAE would be 'unreasonable' to be part of the true time series model and that would be considered an anomaly.

But I have also see MSE (mean square error), and MAD (median average deviation) used. If you want to assume normality you can also use MSE * 3 standard deviations.  What is important is that you establish some reasonable cutoff by vizualization and include the business in the rule making decision, or you can look at previous research studies for whatever you happen to be studying and see what is typically used, since variances can be different across different domains.

Every time series has an error component. That is what you are essentially trying to measure. It is also possible that the errors can be localized (not averaged across all predictions) and can vary based upon some unknown, or improperly measured feature in the model. That you don't know, and that is why the errors are usually averaged over the model.

The test data set is only used to validate the abnormalities. You can't have 2 thresholds, since you are only using 1 cutoff point.

Comment: Ok, thankyou for your time